# ListView not deleting items in Xamarin.Forms. I have assigned an ObservableCollection to the ListView itemsource. MVVM

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

In my Xamarin.Forms app I have a simple Contact class [Model]. In the UI [View] there exists a ListView that displays the Contacts. In my model view class I have a list of Contacts  (_listOfContacts) that is assigned to the itemSource property of the ListView. This list of Contacts is an ObservableCollection. My issue is the when user clicks Delete from ContextActions I can see that the _listOfContacts is updated but the ListView is not.
The ListView is only updated when I reassign its itemsource to the _listOfContacts. This should not be needed if _listOfContacts is an ObservableCollection of Contacts.
I am new to MVVM so I need to clear these basic MVVM concepts before I go on to learn more advanced techniques.
Here is my code:

Model

```
 class Contact
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
    public String ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Model View

```
public partial class ContactListPage : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<Contact> _listOfContacts;
    public ContactListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _listOfContacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>
        {
           new Contact {Name="Item1", ImageUrl="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1" , Status="Hey"},
            new Contact { Name = "Item2", ImageUrl = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2", Status="Hey" },
        };

        contactList.ItemsSource = _listOfContacts.ToList();
    }

    private void EditContactClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Alert", "Clicked Edit", "Cancel");
    }

    private void DeleteContactClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var contact = (sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as Contact;
        _listOfContacts.Remove(contact);
//following line of code should not be needed since _listOfContacts is 
//an ObservableCollection and removing an item should update the bound control automatically
        **contactList.ItemsSource = _listOfContacts.ToList();**
    }
}
```

View

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="contactList" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,2,0,2"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Status}" Margin="0,2,0,2" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem Text="Edit" Clicked="EditContactClick" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            <MenuItem Text="Delete" Clicked="DeleteContactClick" IsDestructive="True" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code, it is just the method `ToList()`which caused this question:

```
 contactList.ItemsSource = _listOfContacts.ToList();
```

At the beginning, the type of `_listOfContacts` is ObservableCollection, but when you use the method `ToList()`,then it will been converted to `List` again.
So just delete the method 'ToList()', your code will work properly, just as follows:

```
contactList.ItemsSource = _listOfContacts;
```

Comment: Correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.toList()` from `contactList.ItemsSource = _listOfContacts.ToList();` and try again.

`_listOfContacts` is an `ObservableCollection` which should be used as your `ItemsSource` directly. Maybe go and check out the [ObservableCollection documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Yep that fixed it! Thanks for your help.